# Why tensorflow python3 script runs slower in ROS than standalone?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, performance

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ubuntu 18.04
ROS Melodic
Python 3.6.8
Tensorflow: 1.13.1
TensorRT: 5.1.5
NVIDIA: GTX1060 using Cudnn 7.6 and Cuda 10.0

When I run a object detection model developed in python using tensorflow framework in ros, the speed appears to be slower than if i run the same tensorflow model in pure python environment. Is this expected behaviour?

I tried tensorflow object detection model named "ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco_2018_03_29"
`python3 tensorflow_inference.py`  --> takes 16ms approx.
`rosrun inference_node inference.py` --> takes 22ms approx

Just for information my catkin workspace is build with python3 too.

For example  my model stats below
`python3 tensorflow_inference.py` ---> takes 60ms approximately
But
`rosrun inference_node inference.py` and subscribing to an image broadcasted by a bag file --> takes 85ms approx.

This seems strange or I am missing some point.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/329557/why-tensorflow-python3-script-runs-slower-in-ros-than-standalone?/) by [npscars](https://answers.ros.org/users/44374/npscars/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2019-07-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found out the reason why this was happening was because the image size input to python3 directly was a bit smaller than the input to ros node. Sorry for confusion but thought would be still useful for someone who might experience this issue like me.

---

Originally posted by [npscars](https://answers.ros.org/users/44374/npscars/) with karma: 16 on 2019-10-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0